USB disk converted to iso9660 and unreadable by Gparted
Recently I upgraded from 23.10 to 24.04. Somehow the upgrade converted my external USB 3TB drive to something that Gparted only recognises as "iso9660" and it shows the whole drive as unallocated.
However the partititions are still there, mounts within Nemo and fdisk -l shows all partititions.
lsblk -e7 -o MODEL,NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT
MODEL               NAME     SIZE FSTYPE  LABEL                  MOUNTPOINT
/  cut /
ST3000DM001-1E6166  sdc      2.7T iso9660 Ubuntu 24.04 LTS amd64 
                    ├─sdc1   160G                                
                    ├─sdc2     8K                                
                    ├─sdc3     3M                                
                    ├─sdc4   200M                                
                    ├─sdc5   200M                                   
                    ├─sdc6   200M ext4                           
                    ├─sdc7   200M                                
                    ├─sdc8   100M                                
                    └─sdc9   2.3T ext4    Samsung                /media/jamaas/Samsung

How can I recover it such that Gparted will allow me to work on partitions and remove problem bootable flags?

If fdisk -l shows all partitions, it sounds like a bug in gparted.

Please run the terminal window command lsblk -e7 -o model,name,size,fstype,label,mountpoints and paste its output into your original question, render it as code. This will help us see what you have (and help us help you).

@sudodus Done!  Thx. J

For some reason the device is seen as an iso file. Some data has been written to the head of the drive, and it is identified by gparted and lsblk. The question is how much of the drive that is 'overwritten': Only a small part (within the first few bytes or less) or as much as the size of the iso file (5.7 gibibyte) or something in between. The fact that you see the partitions sdc1--sdc9 indicates that only a small part at the head of the drive is overwritten. But it also depends on the history of the system ...

Is the system rebooted after the release-upgrade? What did you cut off from the output? How was the system booted (from which system) when you created the output from lsblk? Can you boot in the release-upgraded system? What happens when you try to boot into the drive /dev/sdc with size 2.7 TiB (3 TB)?

Also Jim, I would try and boot from a 22.04 live USB and check if you get the same reading. It might just be a huge detection bug in some library fdisk and Gparted rely on, it's kinda insane to think this would've happened. Granted, it may be, but still, I would first check the most plausible causes. Other than that if really this happened and just the primary partition table has been erased, you should be able to recover the original partition table using gdisk. I'll write an answer if needed, but I would try and avoid messing with stuff that don't need messing with.

Thx @kos.  This sounds like it.  Amazing if there are still bugs in libraries after all this time.  I ended up copying necessary files, reformatting under 24.04 and copying back.  Just something to watch for when upgrading.  Some other strange things have happened.  I've used ubuntu for at least 3 lts's but this upgrade is by far the worst, so be careful.

It's kinda insane to think this could've happened.
I highly suspect this could be due to a detection bug in a library shared between Gparted and lsblk, since both seem to agree on the disk's format. So before trying riskier stuff I would first try and exclude this possibility.
First, check the output of fdisk -l /dev/sdc. Does fdisk agree with Gparted / lsblk?
If so, try and boot from a live 22.04 USB and see if you still detect the drive as ISO9660.
If Gparted / lsblk / fdisk detect the same on 22.04, than you may try and do the following.
Note: this involves messing with the partition table even further!!! We don't know what happened for sure, so I'm not 100% confident stating this won't be detrimental to your current situation. Furthermore, this will work only if your drive was originally formatted as GPT (which seems like the case considering the number of partitions on the drive).
I understand it's unlikely you'll have the facility to perform a full disk backup (such as a spare 3TB drive) before trying this out, but if you have the means to do it, perform a full disk backup before trying this out.
Technically, backing up just the sectors before the first partition should also work in order to be able to restore the drive to the previous state in case something goes wrong while doing this (something like sudo dd if=/dev/sdc bs=1M count=1 >disk_start_backup.dd with all partitions unmounted should be safe without having to delve into counting sectors etc), but I insist that, if possible, you perform a full disk backup instead.

To try and recover the original partition table, assuming the drive is still mapped to /dev/sdc as shown in the lsblk output you posted, you should first unmount every mounted partition (sudo umount /dev/sdc*) and then try and run sudo gdisk /dev/sdc inputting, separated by ENTER:

x
r
b
w
q

that will essentially:

Load the backup GPT partition table as the main partition table
Write the change to the disk
Exit

After having done this, sudo partprobe /dev/sdc should be enough to get the kernel to probe the drive again and for the changes to show up in Gparted / lsblk / fdisk.

If an ISO file was written to the drive at some point in time, and then later a partition table was written, then the problem might simply be that there are some residual ISO signature bytes that were not cleared.
I believe one can use a command like:
sudo wipefs -n --no-act /path-to-disk-device

where "/path-to-disk-device" is something like "/dev/sda"
which should show the signatures on the disk.
If there is a left-over ISO signature then the "wipefs" command can be used to remove the signature.  See "man wipefs".

This also makes sense. I'm happy you brought up this wipefs thing, I've never stumbled upon it! It could come in handy

Thx Curtis, could well be that, but why done upon dist upgrade?

There were changes in how GParted uses other libraries to determine which signatures take priority in order to minimize the chance of overwriting information.  If GParted sees ISO signatures then those take priority over a partition table.  With the dist-upgrade it is likely that such a newer version of GParted was installed.
